# Magento246 ProductAttachment Ui_Component grid not working properly

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I am trying to show all my attachments in my grid but the grid is showing only the last one that I uploaded, but in the database and on the frontend it shows all and when i do filter it show all without filter its only show last one.
can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Advance

this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="tekfile_file_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AmfileFileGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_columns.ids</item>
                  
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">history_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="tekfile/file/massDelete"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="tekfile_file_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tekfile_file_listing.tekfile_file_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_name" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">File Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="product_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product SKU</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_size" class="Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FileSize">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">File Size</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DownloadFile">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">tekfile/file/download</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is column:

```
<?php

namespace Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Attachment;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Upload extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const NAME = 'attachment';

    const ALT_FIELD = 'name';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface                          $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory                        $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param array                                     $components
     * @param array                                     $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            $storeId = $this->context->getRequestParam('store');

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$fieldName . '_form_key'] = $this->getFormKey();
                $item[$fieldName . '_upload_max_size'] = $this->getMaxFileSize();
                $item[$fieldName . '_store_id'] = $storeId;
                $item[$fieldName . '_upload_url'] = $this->getUploadUrl();
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }


    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Model\File
     */
    protected function getFileModel()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->get('Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Model\File');
    }

    protected function getFormKey()
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKeyInstance
         */
        $formKeyInstance = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');

        return $formKeyInstance->getFormKey();
    }

    protected function getUploadUrl()
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Url $urlBuilder
         */
        $urlBuilder = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\UrlFactory')->create();

        return $urlBuilder->getUrl('tekfile/product/upload', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    protected function getMaxFileSize() {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Size $uploaderSize
         */
        $uploaderSize = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\File\Size');

        return $uploaderSize->getMaxFileSize();
    }
}
```

---

```
    <?php

namespace Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Attachment extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const NAME = 'attachment';

    const ALT_FIELD = 'name';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface                          $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory                        $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param array                                     $components
     * @param array                                     $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            $productIds = array_column($dataSource['data']['items'], 'entity_id');
            $storeId = $this->context->getRequestParam('store');
            $files = $this->getFileModel()->getFilesProductGrid($productIds, $storeId);
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $product = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($item);
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) . ' Attachment';
                $item[$fieldName . '_list'] 
                    = array_key_exists($product->getEntityId(), $files)
                        ? $files[$product->getEntityId()] : [];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Model\File
     */
    protected function getFileModel()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->get('Tekglide\ProductAttachment\Model\File');
    }
}
```

frontend

Comment: Please share your di.xml and table primary key column name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **"storageConfig"** in **dataSource**.

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
         <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">history_id</item>
         </item>
      </item>
</argument>
```